# C++.net Delegate not working - compiler error

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, delegates, invoke

Right I created a new thread from a static function from the same class.

Inside the same class I try to call a delegate to update the GUI.
I get a compiler error saying:

**Invalid delegate initializer - an object is needed in addition to a function.**
At &MainUi::AddListItemMethod.

```
delegate void AddListItem(void);
    public: void AddListItemMethod(String^ myString)
    {
        ListView1->Items->Add(myString);
    }

private: static void SecondThread()
{  
AddListItem^ del = gcnew AddListItem(&MainUI::AddListItemMethod);
del->Invoke("test");
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I also tried this and still failed. Any help please?

```
Invoke(gcnew AddListItem(MainUI::&AddListItemMethod), "test");
```

Comment: A method need to be static to be used like this `MainUI::AddListItemMethod`.

Comment: Ok but I need the method to be non-static so it can access the Listview1 control. How can I fix it?

Comment: Either hou have to make `Listview1` static to work or you should create an instance/object of `MainUI` class to access a non static method of that class.

Comment: I made my listview static and called it directly from the second thread. Which seemed to work. Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: welcome, now I posted it as an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Either You have to make `Listview1` static to work or you should create an instance/object of `MainUI` class to access a non static method of that class.

Thank you and Happy coding.